# Dynamically generate LINQ (member-)expressions

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I am using FluentValidation to validate my form items in Xamarin.Forms. The definition of these items comes from the outside. Therefore I don't know, what properties I need to validate on my viewmodel.

```
RuleFor(viewmodel => viewmodel.Description).NotEmpty();
```

My idea was, to dynamically generate these expressions at runtime.

I created a `List` in the validator to store these expressions.

```
public List<Expression<Func<IViewModel, object>>> RequiredFieldExpressions
    = new List<Expression<Func<IViewModel, object>>>();
```

Before validating my viewmodel, I generate the expressions.

```
var tmpMethod = typeof(TypeHelper).GetRuntimeMethod("GetExpression", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
var tmpGeneric = tmpMethod.MakeGenericMethod(myViewModel.GetType(), typeof(string));
var tmpInvokeResult = tmpGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] {coreObjectPropertyName});
```

The method which creates the expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> GetExpression<T, TProperty>(string inPropertyName) where T : IViewModel
{
    var tmpPropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperties().First(p => p.Name == inPropertyName);

    var tmpEntityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    Expression tmpExpression = Expression.Property(tmpEntityParam, tmpPropertyInfo);

    if (tmpPropertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(TProperty))
    {
        tmpExpression = Expression.Convert(tmpExpression, typeof(TProperty));
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(tmpExpression, tmpEntityParam);
}
```

Now the line which should create the validation rule throws an invalid cast exception.

```
// Cast not valid
RuleFor((Expression<Func<IViewModel, object>>) tmpInvokeResult).NotEmpty();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the method call from

```
var tmpGeneric = tmpMethod.MakeGenericMethod(myViewModel.GetType(), typeof(string));
```

to

```
var tmpGeneric = tmpMethod.MakeGenericMethod(myViewModel.GetType(), typeof(object));
```

**My guess**

Xamarin.Forms uses a portable class library (PCL). It seems like the functionality to cast generic expressions isn't implemented.

It would be nice if somebody could verify this.

**Update**

I am not able to cast generic expressions. Seems like it's just not possible. You need to explicitly convert the expression before returning it.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ufNId4